# Orientdb execute query as user in web

Tags: security, orientdb

In OrientDB we have record-level security. When user execute query (e.g. `select from classX`), he only receives records that he has access to. It is super feature, but how I can use in my web application?

I would like to get logged user from my security context app and execute query. It significantly reduce complicated logic in my code.

I have problem with integrate app user with database user. Have you any idea how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing you can do here is using separate connection pools if you have a limited number of db users, or just use database credentials to instantiate a separate connection per user. How to do it depends a lot on your application architecture.

Comment: I know that I separate connection per user. I have problem with credentials user. How to integrate password user from db and from security application? I can't use password from application to db. For all users in db (without admin) set the same password? Is good solution? Perfect solution for me is create app user and create pool connection and execute query as user x or change from app user to user x (without credentials).